# iPhone Excel generation

Tags: iphone, excel

I'm creating an application that generates purchase order.
I'm able to create text file from the details entered by user.
I would like to generate an Excel which looks much better than a normal text file.
Is there any open source library that I can use in my application?

Comment: Do you want just a CSV file or did you want an actual Excel format file?

Comment: I'm actually looking for Excel format file.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any iphone ready library out there. However what you can do, if you text file isn't that complex:
- create a new excel doc on your pc (or mac it would take a bit of extra work)
- add a dummy text in first cell, save and close excel
- now change the extension of the .xlsx file to xml
- find where your dummy text is

now you have a placeholder and a patter that you can leverage to add additional content.
On the phone you can find the place holder, insert your text and save. The result will be what you're looking for. I have done that manually and works fine. Again if your scenario is simple. Otherwise there're many relationships in the xml that involve more parsing and debugging time :-)